# Inheritance with NHibernate mapping and Abstract class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I am trying to map an class which two other classes will inherit from, i wish to make it abstract so i will be able to return a list which containing two type of child object and cast them accordingly with a discriminator in the parent class.

For an example of my codes, BD looks like the following:
[image]

Here are my Domain models:

```
public class Person
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public string subject{get; set;}
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public string grade{get; set;}
}
```

And my Nhibernate mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="Domain.Model" assembly="Domain" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="false">
    <class name="Person" table="`Person`" schema="`PR`">
        <id name="id" access="property" column="`id`">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>

        <property name="id" type="int" column="`id`" />
        <property name="name" type="String" column="`name`" />

        <joined-subclass name="Teacher" table="`Teacher`" schema="`PR`">
            <key column="`id`" />
            <property name="subject" type="String" column="`subject`" />
        </joined-subclass>
        <joined-subclass name="Student" table="`Student`" schema="`PR`">
            <key column="`id`" />
            <property name="grade" type="String" column="`grade`" />
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I wish to make my "Person" class abstract so I will be able to have a list that can contain both child type but I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) does not require the base class to be abstract. You can work on a `List<Person>` containing `Teacher` and `Student` instances without having `Person` being abstract.

Setting `Person` as abstract in code only forbid to create a `Person` instance.

Setting `Person` as abstract in NHibernate mapping with a 'table per subclass' model tells to NHibernate that the `Person` table must have a corresponding entry in one of the subclass table. If your DB contain some rows in `Person` without any corresponding row in `Student` or `Teacher`, then this is an error.

Maybe this [blog](https://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance) could help better understand what you should do.